# How do I change the width of a Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I have two main Layouts on my home page. The first is a RelativeLayout (with the ID "tabView") and the second is a LinearLayout (with the ID "menuView"). Both of these layouts exist inside one RelativeLayout (with the ID "parentView"). By default tabView has the height and width of parentView while menuView has the height of parentView, but width is set to 0dp. I want the menuView to slide to the right so that it's width is equal to 20% of the parentView and tabView's width should change to 80% of the parentView to accommodate. However, with the code I have, the measurements are not changing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parentView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabhostcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

LinearLayout menuView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuView);
            RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);
            RelativeLayout tabView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabhostcontainer);
            Log.v(tabViewTag, Integer.toString(tabView.getWidth()));
            Log.v(parentViewTag, Integer.toString(parentView.getWidth()));

            menuView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (parentView.getWidth()*.2), menuView.getHeight()));
            tabView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (parentView.getWidth()*.8), tabView.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess up with the code layout. This was my asking a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Set weight of menuView as 1 and that of tabsView to 4.. it will create 1:4 ratio i.e 20%-80%
set width of both layouts to 0dp

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear, but I am trying to change them during runtime. Basically, the user will press a menu button and the menuView will have its width changed from 0dp to 20% of the parentView while tabView will have its width changed from match_parent to 80% of the parentView. I do not want them set to 20% and 80% initially.

Comment: OK, the way I implemented this was using fragments. Initially I would set menuView fragments visibility to View.GONE. When the user will click on menu button, it will change to View.VISIBLE. You can check out tutorials for multi-pane views...It will give you some idea.... this may not be the best way to achieve what you want.. so if you do find a better way, do let me know!